# How to pass subnet ids to aws_network_interface which has count attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting the 3 existing subnet ids using data resource as below

```
data "aws_subnet" "AZA" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

 filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["my-subnet-1a"]
  }

}
```

Similarly I'm getting AZB and AZC as well. Now I need to pass these subnet ids to aws_network_interface resource which has count attribute.

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "my_network_interface" {
    count          = 3
    private_ips     = [var.private_ips[count.index]]
    subnet_id       = ???
```

How do I pass subnet_id in each iteration?

Comment: Its not possible to get 3 subnets from `data.aws_subnet`. The data source can return only one. Thus its not clear what you are doing exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way is to use [aws_subnets](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnets#filter) (not `aws_subnet`):

```
data "aws_subnets" "AZ" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["my-subnet-1a", "my-subnet-1b", "my-subnet-1c"] 
  }
}
```

then

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "my_network_interface" {
    count          = 3
    private_ips     = [var.private_ips[count.index]]
    subnet_id       = data.aws_subnets.AZ.ids[count.index]
}
```

Comment: As a side note, there is a closing curly bracket missing.

Comment: @MarkoE Just copied OP's code:-)

Comment: Copy+paste on StackOverflow?! xD

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation. I have used locals to concat the subnet ids

```
locals {
  subnets = concat([data.aws_subnet.AZA.id],[data.aws_subnet.AZB.id],[data.aws_subnet.AZC.id])
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "my_network_interface" {
    count          = 3
    private_ips    = [var.private_ips[count.index]]
    subnet_id      = local.subnets[count.index]
```

Comment: Why not `subnets = [data.aws_subnet.AZA.id, data.aws_subnet.AZB.id, data.aws_subnet.AZC.id]`. Is there any purpose for concat here?

Comment: Good question. I dint even think. I experimented with not using locals like below.


`subnet_id       = element(concat(tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.AZA.ids), tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.AZB.ids), tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.AZC.ids)),count.index)`

Just dint think that concat is redundant.